# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-requests

```
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
```

At line 2 I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I have imported requests and installed requests. How do I debug this error? can anyone tell command to install lastest requests module?

Comment: Please format (indent) the code in your question. It's impossible to read like this.

Comment: What version of `requests` is this? This is not an error I'd expect a current version of the library to raise. What does `print(requests.__version__)` show?

Comment: 0.8.2 is the version number

Comment: Use a newer version?
The version is already 2.x.x now.

Comment: This specific version of `requests.Response` doesn't have a `text` attribute: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.8.2/api/#requests.Response you should use a more recent version

Comment: can anyone tell the command to install latest requests module?

Comment: `pip install --upgrade requests` or `easy_install requests`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using an ancient version of `requests`, most likely because it came installed with [Ubuntu Precise Pengolin (12.04LTS)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-requests).

You'll either have to refer to the [version specific documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.2/) or use a more recent version. `requests` has changed drastically since the 0.x version days.

For your old version, if you set `response.encoding`, `response.content` will contain a decoded Unicode value.

Comment: Very important - your are a real samaritan!

Comment: I just got this error with flasks response object. Do you have any idea if there is something similar?

Comment: @MartinThoma that’s an entirely different project. Yes, like any project, Flask also has multiple releases, and the Flask `Response` class inherits from a class defined by the Werkzeug project. Make sure you look at the documentation for the versions you are actually using.

Comment: @MartinThoma that said, I’m not aware of any version of Flask or Werkzeug where the `Response` class ever had a `.text` attribute.  So it sounds as if you have faulty code.