# Python requests error version 2.4.1

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having an error with python requests module. This is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests

url = 'http://www.mingeford365.co.uk/forum/ucp.php?mode=login'

logininfo = {'username': '',
             'password': ''}

headers = {'Host': 'www.mingeford365.co.uk',
           'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (x11; Ubuntu; Linux x86; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0', 
           'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xhtml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-gb,en;q=0.5', 
           'Accept-Encoding':  'gzip, deflate',                                   
           'referer': 'http://www.mingeford365.co.uk/forum/viewforum.php?f=4',
           'Cookie' : '',
           'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

r = requests.session()
r.post(url,params=logininfo,headers=headers)

print (r.text)
```

I keep getting the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./BasicLogin.py", line 22, in <module>
    print (r.text)
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I found a similar question on here before. [AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689334/attributeerror-response-object-has-no-attribute-text)

However, the solution was to have the most recent version of requests installed. I already have the most recent version installed, ive reinstalled pip and pip3 and redownloaded requests for both, have then tried the upgrade and it tells me i have the up to date version.

However I still get the same error message. I've tried the code in python 3 and python 2.7 and I still get the same error, I've tried `r.status_code`, `r.text` and `r.content` and still get the sessions has no attribute error.

I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 2):

`r` is still the session. You need to use the return value of `r.post()` instead:

```
session = requests.session()
response = session.post(
    url, params=logininfo, headers=headers
)
print(response.text)
```

Variables renamed on purpose. Please don't be the guy who infects code with ugly variable names. :)

Answer (score 0):

`r` is your **session object**, not the response. The `r.post()` method *returns* a response, use *that* instead:

```
response = r.post(url, params=logininfo, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

You probably want to avoid 1 letter variables; use `session` for your session object for example:

```
session = requests.session()
response = session.post(url, params=logininfo, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Now it is much clearer what object you are using.