# I'm trying to create a crawler for my wordpress website using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-crawler

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def page(current_page):
    current = "h2"
    while current == current_page:
        url = 'https://vishrantkhanna.com/?s=' + str(current)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.txt
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('h2', {'class': 'entry-title'}):
            href = "https://vishrantkhanna.com/" + link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            print(href)
            print(title)

page("h2")
```

I'm trying to copy and print the article title and the href link associated with it.

Comment: What is the expected and the real result of your code? And what's the error/issue you are facing? Any log/sample result would be very helpful for the ppl who'd like to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the `<a>` tag from the heading:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://vishrantkhanna.com/?s=1'

html = requests.get(URL).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for link in bs.find_all('h2', {'class': 'entry-title'}):
    a = link.find('a', href=True)
    href = "https://vishrantkhanna.com/" + a.get('href')
    title = link.string
    print(href)
    print(title)
```

Comment: You are using an old version of `requests`, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392780/1416672).